# Swing JList and DefaultListModel.

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jlist

How I can get a selected item?

I have a simple requirement in my code: I need to get a selected item to realize a `ActionListener` that is enable a `JButton`.

```
    public class Tela extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DefaultListModel<String> model;
    private JList<String> list;

    public Tela(){
        setTitle("Maquina de Refrigerante");
         String labels[] = { "Coca-Cola", "Fanta Laranja", "Fanta-Uva", 
                 "Sprite"};

        //Cria os Paineis no Frame
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel downPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        rightPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rightPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        list = new JList<String>(labels);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
        pane.getViewport().add(list);  
        leftPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        leftPanel.add(pane);

        final JButton comprar = new JButton("Comprar");
        comprar.setEnabled(false);       
        rightPanel.add(comprar);
        rightPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,4)));
        rightPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 20));

        panel.add(leftPanel);
        panel.add(rightPanel);
        panel.add(downPanel);
        add(panel);

        setSize(450, 350);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        comprar.addActionListener(new Paga());
    }


}
```

I want to implement an `ActionListener` that get the item selected and so enable a `jbutton("Comprar")`, but I don't have any idea at this moment to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSelectedIndex()` and [`getSelectedIndices()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedIndices%28%29) will give the index of the selected item

In addition to **MadProgrammer**'s answer, It is preferable to use [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#addListSelectionListener%28javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener%29) of listening for selection state changes event. `JList` takes care of listening for selection state changes in the selection model, and notifies the given listener of each change. Use it as follows:

```
jList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
               selectedValues = jList1.getSelectedValuesList(); 
                        // it will return a list of values
                        //evt.getFirstIndex() - the index of last selected item
                       //evt.getLastIndex() - the index of current selected item
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Wesley, happy to hear that. But beware, `ListSelectionListener` will be fired twice on one item's selection lost and another item's selection gain

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`JList#getSelectedValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValue%28%29) to return the item which is currently selected.

Take a look at [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details about registering an action listener to your button and [How to use lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for details about using `JList`s

Comment: uhh you have answered. sorry, I will remove mine one then

Comment: uhh, i just thought i should mention about `ListSelectionListener`. Didn't remove but mentioned your name in the post. and +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer I used so `list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
               String selectedValue = list.getSelectedValue();
               System.out.println("Value"+selectedValue);
               comprar.setEnabled(true);
                          
            }
        });` but it get a duplicated value why?

Comment: @Wesley You will get at two events because the the selection model will be firing a deselected and selected event

Comment: @Sage I just saw the mention of `JButton` and `ActionListener`

Comment: @Wesley, I have already answered that in my comment. I have commented out two line with code for you too. Check them

Comment: @MadProgrammer, :) yes